# Restoring a column of a DevExpress GridControl

Tags: c#-4.0, gridview, layout, devexpress, datagridviewcolumn

I have a DevExpress GridView where I add a column, then save the layout:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This magically creates a column which I don't want, so delete it
    gridControl1.DataSource = new ObservableCollection<object> { new object() };
    var gridView = ((GridView)gridControl1.MainView);
    gridView.Columns.Clear();

    // Create the column I want
    var myColumn = new GridColumn { Name = "MyColumn", Caption = "MyColumn" };
    gridView.Columns.Add(myColumn);
    // At this point, the column is not displayed yet 
    // And it's not displayed in the column chooser panel
    gridView.Columns[0].Visible = true;
    // The column is visible now and available in the column chooser

    // Awesome layout now, let's save it
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        gridControl1.MainView.SaveLayoutToStream(stream, GetLayoutOptions());
        layoutXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
    }
}
```

This gives a nice XML which contains my column:

```
<XtraSerializer version="1.0" application="View">
...
  <property name="Columns" iskey="true" value="1">
    <property name="Item1" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Visible">true</property>
      <property name="VisibleIndex">0</property>
      <property name="Name">MyColumn</property>
    </property>
  </property>
...
</XtraSerializer>
```

Then, the user can do something else, e.g. change the layout

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = ((GridView)gridControl1.MainView);
    gridView.Columns.Clear();
}
```

Back on topic, he wants to see the "old" view:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(layoutXml)))
    {
        gridControl1.MainView.RestoreLayoutFromStream(stream, GetLayoutOptions());
    }
}
```

But the column is not displayed. Looking at `((GridView)gridControl1.MainView).Columns` in the debugger shows a column count of 0.

Doing a bit of research, I found out in the [DevExpress Forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q272127) that I need to set options when saving and reading the layout, so I adapted my code to include the suggested method (already used in the code above):

```
private OptionsLayoutGrid GetLayoutOptions() {
    OptionsLayoutGrid layoutGrid = new OptionsLayoutGrid();
    layoutGrid.StoreAllOptions = true;
    layoutGrid.StoreAppearance = true;
    return layoutGrid;
}
```

Still no luck.

**How do I get back columns of a layout?**

I'm aware that I could parse the XML myself and add the column programmatically, but ... well ... I'd expect that as a built-in functionality of the GridControl/GridView.

Adding

```
layoutGrid.Columns.AddNewColumns = true;
```

as proposed in [another DevExpress Forum post](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q303979) also doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns you wish to retrieve exist in the saved layout, but do not exist in the grid, it is necessary to set the **OptionsLayoutGrid.Columns.RemoveOldColumns** property to false. In this case, the **OptionsLayoutGrid.Columns.StoreAllOptions** option should be enabled.